# $\displaystyle d(f,g)=\sup_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|+ \sup_{a\leq x \leq b} |f'(x)-g'(x)|, \quad f,g \in X$. Then d is a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Hello *stackexchange*!

(Firstly, I'm sorry if this question asked before like that, I've searched something on this website but I couldn't find an answer such I wanted)

Let $X$ be the set of all continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$.

$\displaystyle d(f,g)=\sup_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|+ \sup_{a\leq x \leq b} |f'(x)-g'(x)|, \quad f,g \in X$.

Then d is a metric on X.

Well, today I focused on this problem and tried that:

Firstly, let $$d_{1}(f,g) := \sup_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)| \quad f,g \in X$$
and $$d_{2}(f,g) := \sup_{a\leq x \leq b} |f'(x)-g'(x)|, \quad f,g \in X$$
So, if $d_{1}(f,g)$ and $d_{2}(f,g)$ are metrics, then $d(f,g) = d_{1}(f,g) + d_{2}(f,g)$ is also a metric.

We can easily show that $d_{1}(f,g)$ is a metric.
But we know, $d_{2}(f,g)$ is not a metric. (For example, let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be a constant function.)
So, $\textbf{this way doesn't work!}$
Unfortunately, I stuck at that point.

I'm open for any small pieces of hints! Thanks!

Comment: If $d_1$ is a metric then you don't need $d_2$ to be a metric for $d_1 + d_2$ to be a metric. You only need $d_2$ to be symmetric and satisfy the triangle inequality (i.e. $d_2$ only needs to be a pseudometric). It would be a good exercise to try to check that. This is the case you are in here, though its also not so hard to check that $d$ is a metric directly.

Comment: Why don't you just try the definition. Show that the triangle inequality holds, that $d(f, g) = d (g, f)$ and that $d(f , g) = 0$ iff $f=g$

Answer (score 1):

You do not need that $d_2$ is a metric. It suffices that it is a *pseudometric*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space. But this is trivial because $d_2(f,g) = d_1(f',g')$.

Then clearly $d = d_1 +d_2$ is a pseudometric. It is a metric because $d_1(f,g) \le d(f,g)$: If $d(f,g)= 0$, then also $d_1(f,g) = 0$.